# ListVIew's item layout height depending on the amount of items

Tags: android, listview

I have ListView of items and I want to set the height of each item depending on the amount of items in order the listview to fullfill the screen.

First i get the window size without bar:

```
//returns height of the app window in pixels
public static int windowHeight(Context context){

        int barH = 0; //bar height
        int height = 125;//DpToPx(context, 125); //default
        int displayH;

    try {
        //getting stastus bar height
        int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            barH = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }

        //getting all the screen height

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            display.getSize(size);
            displayH = size.y;

        } else {
            //noinspection deprecation
            displayH = display.getHeight();
        }

        height = displayH - barH;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return height;
    }
```

Then in MenuAdapter I am trying to set height:

```
//set up the height of listrow depending on the amount of menu items in order the listview to fullfill the screen
private void setupRowHeight(LinearLayout l) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)l.getLayoutParams();
    int margin = lp.topMargin + lp.bottomMargin;
    int itemsAmount = content.size();
    lp.height = Util.windowHeight(context) / itemsAmount - margin*itemsAmount;
    Log.i("height of row", String.valueOf(l.getLayoutParams().height) + " " + String.valueOf(margin));


}
```

}

And LinearLayout in RowLayout.xml is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/elem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/row_height"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bord"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/row_margin_horiz"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/row_margin_horiz"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/row_margin_vert"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/row_margin_vert">
    .....................................................
    </LinearLayout>
```

But the items appeear not exactly having a bit more or less height. 
I just don't get what I didn't take into account?

Comment: What are you filling the rows with? Text? Does the row get bigger if its more populated or does it happen randomly? A picture would be nice to help us understand better your problem.

Comment: I fill it with an image and textView. The height i set for them depends on the height of the linearLayout. There's no problem with that. The only problem is that the height of linearLayout sets not 100% correctly.

Comment: Is the difference in height always the same? For example if you want it to be 20dp its 5dp more/less? Or is it random? If it is standard you could set an offset.